# How can I scrape all the comments on the site?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to scrape all the comments (436 comments) of the macbook product on the e-commerce site I shared below, but it didn't scrape all the comments, it cut it in half. How Can I Solve This?

![Sample Code][1]

### browser=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Emre/Desktop/Elif/web_scraping/chromedriver.exe") browser.get("https://www.trendyol.com/apple/macbook-air-13-m1-8gb-256gb-ssd-uzay-grisi-p-68042136") Brand=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product-detail-app']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/h1/a").text Brand_name=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product-detail-app']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/h1").text Price=browser.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='product-detail-app']/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/div/div/div/div[2]/span").text Assesment=browser.find_element_by_class_name("rvw-cnt-tx") Assesment.click() time.sleep(5) for i in range(1,5): browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)') time.sleep(5) Assesments= browser.find_elements_by_class_name("pr-rnr-com") #degerlendirmeler= browser.find_elements_by_class_name("rnr-com-tx") Assesment_List=[] for Assesment in Assesments: Assesment_List.append(Assesment.text) with open ("customer_comments.txt","w",encoding = "UTF-8") as file: for Assesment in Assesment_List: file.write(Assesment + "/n") time.sleep(5)

Comment: My codes worked properly, and I didn't get any error. I was able to scrape only some of the comments of Macbook product. How can I scrape all of the comments ?

Comment: The page you shared doesn't go anywhere. Is it a good link?

Comment: Hi el%c4%b0f-%c3%96zcan - please paste your code as text - so people can try it.  And @DiegoCuadros has a point ..

Comment: https://www.trendyol.com/apple/macbook-air-13-m1-8gb-256gb-ssd-uzay-grisi-p-68042136  Yeap it is correct link

Comment: I've just shared my codes as text but, format is bad I know.. because of I'm new in stackoverflow I'm sorry guys :( I hope I will be able to solve this problem in my codes and I scrape my data..